# Login verify password/confirm password is not working. PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

For some reason my verify password is not working in my php. Not sure if it is the command or if I am missing something. I want it to not allow a user to login if the password is incorrect.

HTML and PHP below.

```html
<HTML>

  <HEAD>
    <TITLE> Programming </TITLE>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" href="homework2.css"> 

    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

      <!-- CSS for http://the7.dream-demo.com/ -->

      <div id="container">
        
        <div id="header">
          <div class="menuitem"> <a href="home.html">Home</a> </div>
          <div class="menuitem"><a href="products.html">Products</a></div>
          <div class="menuitem"><a href="cases.html">Case Studies</a></div>
          <div class="menuitem"><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></div>
          <div class="menuitem"><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></div>
        </div>

        <div id="bodycontent">
          
          <div id="banner">
           <div id="bannerleft"> <h1> We make you better athletes. Find out how! </h1> </div>
           <div id="signin"> 
             
             <form class="well form-inline" action="login.php" method="post">

              <input type="text" class="input-small" placeholder="Email"  name="email" >
              <input type="password" class="input-small" placeholder="Password" name="password">
              <br><br>

<!--
  If you do not want to use twitter bootstrap css then you should uncomment next 6 lines and uncomment the
  above 2 lines that provide input boxes

     <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
     <br>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
     <br>
    -->

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="logmein" value="Log In">
  </form>
  
</div>

</div>
<div id="featurestrip"> 

  
  <div id="signup">

    <form action="signup.php" method="post">

     
     <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
     <input type="text" name="signup-firstname" id="signup-firstname">
     <br>

     <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
     <input type="text" name="signup-lastname" id="signup-lastname">
     <br>

     <label for="email">Email:&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
     <input type="text" name="signup-email" id="signup-email">
     <br>
     <label for="password">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="signup-password" id="signup-password">
     <br>
     <label for="password">Reconfirm Password:</label>
     <input type="password" name="signup-repassword" id="signup-repassword">
     <br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="signmeup" id="signmeup" value="Sign Me Up!">
   </form>

 </div>

 <div id="featureright"> <p>Sign up and find out more on how we can help. Pricing starts at $19.95 a month. </p>
  <p><h3>Premium service starts at $49.95.</h3></p>

</div>   


</div>
<div id="corefeatures"> 



 <img height="200px" src="http://www.hockeymanitoba.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/ltad-model.jpg">
</div>

<div id="testimonials"> Testimonial
  <img height="200px" src="http://www.neuroexplosion.com/storage/development%20model%20jpeg.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1305662626397">

  <img height="200px" src="http://www.phecanada.ca/sites/default/files/physical_literacy/LTAD_FMS.jpg">
</div>
       <!--
       <div id="portfolio"> Portfolio</div>
       <div id="skills"> Skills</div>
     -->
   </div>
   
   <div id="footer">Copyright Notice. All Rights Reserved. 2014</div>

 </div>

 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

PHP

```
    <?php



$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'username';
$mysql_password = 'password';
$mysql_database = 'db_users2015';

$connect = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die ("Couldn't connect");

echo "<BR>Connection Successful";

  //to put data into database
  //select database
  $db_selected= mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connect) 
  or die ("Couldn't connect to the database");

  $email= $_POST['email'];
  $password= $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM users WHERE email= '{$_POST['email']}' AND password= '{$_POST['password']}'";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql);

if(["email"]==$email &&["password"]==$password)
   echo ("Login Successful.");

else{
    die("Wrong Password.");
  }


$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE email= '{$_POST['email']}'";
$sql_result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_result($sql_result, 0)<1)
 {
die("<BR>Email address not found");
}

else{
    echo "Login Successful!";
}




?>
```

Comment: Same notes as yesterday. Does the password you are testing with contain a quote? Also what is `["email"]` and `["password"]`? You don't need that if `$sql_result` is true then the email and password matched. But DONT do that separate the user input from your query.

Comment: I see what you are mentioning there, I changed the quotes to match, thank you again for your assistance today chris85. I was trying to use email and password to essentially match the email and password in the database to make sure it is a correct login. You are saying I don't need to even add those variables in the section that is below?                        if ($sql_result["email"] == $email && $sql_result["password"] == $password)
   echo ("Login Successful.");
else {
    die("Wrong Password.");
}

Comment: Yes, if it matches in SQL it matched, no need to double check... but again dont pass user input direct to your SQL; and dont store passwords in plain text at a minimum md5 it. There as many tutorials, threads, and functions out there for better approaches. You should update to the `mysqli` or `pdo` driver.

Comment: Actually no, select the userid or something, that I think you will get a count of `0` if none match.

Comment: Also to tag a user you need to append the `@` to their username.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, still learning here. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've selected on your query only the `COUNT(*)` from database where email and password is the same you've received from the form, not the columns to compare, and you too forgot `mysql_fetch_assoc` to fetch the row from database, try this:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*) as qty FROM users WHERE email= '%s' and password = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row['qty']) {...
```

Comment: so, i edited this to add the other $sql_result, still no luck it sticks in a Wrong Password state even when the password is correct.

Comment: No note on how bad of an idea this query is? `SELECT COUNT(*) as qty FROM users WHERE email= '{$_POST['email']}'`

Comment: @ruwadidr try now, i forgot the mysql_fetch_assoc, and in your query you select only COUNT(*), not the columns...

Comment: @ruwadidr with mysql_real_escape_string is more secure, i've edited my answer again with the mysql_real_escape_string...

Comment: @ThiagoFrança thanks i'm attempting the changes now.

Comment: @ruwadidr If it work, let me know and please, check as correct to help another users...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not getting, why you are using 2 separate query for checking user. But, it's your requirement, so i posted my answer according to the question.

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = 'localhost';
$mysql_user = 'username';
$mysql_password = 'password';
$mysql_database = 'db_users2015';

$connect = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die ("Couldn't connect");

echo "<BR>Connection Successful";

$db_selected= mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connect) or die ("Couldn't connect to the database");

$email= $_POST['email'];
$password= $_POST['password'];

$QueryEmail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= '$email'");
$CountResultEmail=mysql_num_rows($QueryEmail);

if($CountResultEmail==1)
{
    echo "Correct Email";

    $QueryPassword=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= '$email' AND password='$password'");
    $CountResultPassword=mysql_num_rows($QueryPassword);
    if($CountResultPassword==1)
    {
        echo "Login Successful";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Wrong Password";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Wrong Email";
}
?>
```

You can check Email & Password in one Query. You can use this as well.

```
<?
.
.
$email= $_POST['email'];
$password= $_POST['password'];

$QueryResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= '$email' AND password='$password'");
$CountResult=mysql_num_rows($QueryResult);

if($CountResult==1)
{
    echo "Login Successfull";
}
else
{
    echo "Wrong Credentials";
}
?>
```